# iOS - store data locally ONLY

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

I'm new to iOS development or any native mobile app development and I want to confirm my understanding of database concepts for iOS apps.

My understanding so far is that, for apps like Facebook and Twitter, their central data resides on their web server and their mobile apps just interface and communicate through the API to keep them in sync.

Another type of app could be that it doesn't have any web presense and only started as iOS app. Therefore, its data gets stored only on local storage of a user's device and iOS ORM - Core Data maps with sqlite for this local database.

Is my understanding correct, especially on the latter part?

My app will fall into the latter category and just wanting to know if this is a standard practice to not incorporate data connection over the wire.

Comment: Not sure what exactly the question is, but yes, you can make iOS apps that don't communicate with any server, and you can store data locally (using Core Data or sqlite or files). Depending on your app, though, users these days often expect that data is synchronized across multiple devices, and that will require some server-side presence (not necessarily *your* server, you could use something like iCloud or Dropbox) even if there is no web interface.

Comment: A good practice is to always use local storage. Even you store your data in the cloud, your users might not always have internet connection, so you can display your local data while your users having bad internet. Also, local cache data can reduce the amount of new API requests. In addition, local cache data can improve the performance of your app, for example, your app tried to load a large new image from cloud, but before your request is done, you can display the previous cached image. So, it is always good to have local data and cloud.

Comment: @ztan Thanks. So do app developers need to do anything about enabling data for cloud backup? I thought cloud is natively supported that users choose to do or not do.

Comment: an easy way to enable data for cloud backup is to use Parse API, it has [local database](http://blog.parse.com/2014/12/09/parse-local-datastore-for-ios/) for iOS too, using Parse API can make your app universal, because you can use the data for your android or windows app later. Alternatively, you can store your data with iCloud(cloud) and Core Data(local), you can visit [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SG_XSD84WOc) for more detail, but iCloud + Core Data will make your app only available for iOS.